# DBD::Oracle - A PL/SQL block is not working

Tags: oracle, perl, plsql, dbi

I am trying to execute a PL/SQL code using [`DBD::Oracle`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Oracle). It gets executed without any errors, but the tables don't get dropped.

Here is the code:

```
my @tabs = qw!actor address category city country customer film film_features
film_actor film_category film_text inventory language payment rental staff 
store!; 

for my $ts (@tabs){

    my $csr = $ora->prepare(q{
         DECLARE
              var_count INT;
         BEGIN
             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_count
             FROM sys.all_tables WHERE OWNER = 'SAKILA' AND table_name = :ts ;
                 if var_count > 0 then
                     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE :ts CASCADE CONSTRAINTS' ;
                 end if;
          END;
    });
    $csr->bind_param(":ts", $ts);
    $csr->execute;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.1 - Change the table list into upper case

No.2 - Change :

FROM

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE :ts CASCADE CONSTRAINTS' ;
```

TO:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||:ts||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS' ;
```

Here is the full code :

```
my @tabs = qw!ACTOR ADDRESS CATEGORY CITY COUNTRY CUSTOMER FILM FILM_FEATURES FILM_ACTOR FILM_CATEGORY FILM_TEXT INVENTORY LANGUAGE PAYMENT RENTAL STAFF STORE!;
  for my $ts (@tabs){
     chomp $ts;
     my $csr = $ora->prepare(q{ 
        DECLARE
          var_count INT;
        BEGIN
          SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_count
          FROM sys.all_tables WHERE OWNER = 'SAKILA' AND table_name = :ts ;
            if var_count > 0 then
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||:ts||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS' ;
            end if;
        END;
     });
$csr->bind_param(":ts", $ts);
$csr->execute;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to uppercase the table names, oracle sql is case in-sensitive (unless you explicitly tell it to be case sensitive).

Comment: If I do a select on sys.all_tables with table_name = actor it returns nothing so the condition translates to false and tables don't get dropped but with upper case it works

Comment: UpperCase is needed for `table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'` because it is a string, when referred as a table itself case doesnt matter! And worth mentioning, any DB object cannot be used as binding variable. That's the reason, you have form the String with the table name, instead of binding it. And _bind variable_ for `DDL` actually is a different discussion!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, yes you right. All caps is required for select-statement, but not for drop-statement. And I was just watching on the  drop-statement. I usually use `table_name = upper(:ts)`. Anyway in the answer it's always good to explain not only how but also why.

Answer (score 2):

I would replace

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE :ts CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
```

with

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||:ts||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
```

because dynamic sql will not recognize `:ts` as variable when you put it directly to dynamic query.

Comment: This only fixes one of the two issues. @user3658506 has addressed both issues.

Comment: Yup, I didn't notice that table names weren't upper case. I would then change `:ts` to `UPPER(:ts)` at `WHERE` clause and inside dynamic sql query.